# What should the correct mime-type be for javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular project using an HTTP server I built myself. When I try to load the JS files into my HTML page, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I read other places that this is usually because the files are being loaded directly into the browser. However, I am using a server.

I've tried setting the mime-type to 'application/javascript' and 'text/javascript'. Both throw the same error. Here are the headers coming back:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/public/dist/public/runtime.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 {Content-Type: 'text/javascript'}
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 19 Jan 2020 18:28:27 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

What other reasons could be causing this error?

Comment: [tag:angular] (and [tag:javascript], unless that's what you wrote your server in) is irrelevant here. The problem is the server.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. You are correct. I was configuring the headers imporperly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your header syntax is wrong.

> ```
> Status Code: 200 {Content-Type: 'text/javascript'}
> ```

That should be:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

i.e.

- On a line of its own
- application not text (although text is still supported)
- No quotes

`Status Code` isn't a header. It's part of the first line of the response, which should look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I got the wrong info about setting Node's HTTP headers.

Comment: Per RFC9239 `application/javascript` is obsolete; ` text/javascript` is the only correct JavaScript MIME type.